# Angular 2 Material Design Multi-select Drop-down with Hierarchical Indentation

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am working on creating a customized view for a Multi-select Drop-down in an Angular 2 Material Design application. The requirement asks for a hierarchical indentation of the options shown in the drop-down as shown in the below screen shot.
[image: Multi-select Indented Drop-down]

Basically, the data set that I receive can be either 2 digit, 3 digit or 4 digit in length. I need to apply the indentation according to the length of the data fields.

I have tried multiple options but so far I've been unable to achieve this purpose. The latest code try that I did has the following kind of code snippet:

```
<md-select multiple placeholder="Data" [(ngModel)]="selecteddatas" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
            <md-option *ngFor="let data of datas" [value]="data.value">
                <div *ngIf="{{data.viewValue.length}}==={{2}}">{{ data.viewValue }}</div>
                <div *ngIf="{{data.viewValue.length}}==={{3}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ data.viewValue }}</div>
                <div *ngIf="{{data.viewValue.length}}==={{4}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ data.viewValue }}</div>
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
```

Can somebody guide me regarding the correct way of implementing this or if there is a component available for Angular 2 Material Design that I could use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Youre probably going to want to add some css padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot has checkbox instead of `select` and `option`, so you might want to use `md-checkbox` instead. As for the `*ngIf` checks, you don't need to use interpolation for that.

Using `&nbsp;` for indentation is not the best idea, as you can see in the [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xnJjeM?p=preview), it indents numbers, but not the checkboxes, so taking the css approach as suggested by @cgatian, would be much better choice.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of filteredList">
  <div [ngClass]="{'one-indent': item.number.length == 2, 
                   'two-indent': item.number.length == 3,
                   'three-indent': item.number.length == 4 }">
    <md-checkbox [checked]="item.value">
      {{ item.number }}
    </md-checkbox>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.one-indent{
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.two-indent{
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.three-indent{
  margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nehal! The demo looks almost like the way I need the implementation to be. I'll try out this solution and hopefully this would work the way I expect it.

Comment: Hey Nehul, the demo look really nice. However, there's one issue I found. I need this kind of layout to be available in the drop down i.e. a select option. Is it possible to have this kind of `md-checkbox` layout inside a `md-select` control?

Comment: In the demo, I have added a md-select with checkboxes inside it.

Comment: This is awesome Nehal! Looking really nice. I got another request though for this. I need the select drop-down to be multi-select. When I try adding the Angular 2 option for that like `<md-select multiple>` it doesn't work. Do you know if there's an alternate way to achieve this purpose of having a multi-select dropdown?

Comment: Added multi-select in the demo

Comment: You are amazing Nehal! Thanks a lot for helping me with this. It's looking really nice.

Comment: Hey Nehal, I have a follow up requirement on this feature which is slightly different so I've documented it at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44856434/angular-2-material-design-multi-select-drop-down-hierarchy-parent-selection-stat. Any chance you have some idea to solve that problem?